# Jet 4.0 connection problem with c# windows application

Tags: c#, ms-access, oledb, database-connection

I am developing a win .net application which runs continuously in server machine.  Application will get connected with access(mdb) databases resided in several client  machines using Jet 4.0 OLEDB provider.

Each connected database was already in use by some other application installed locally.

My app successfully communicates with all the databases when client machines are  constantly alive.

But if one of my client machine goes down(say system or network) and rebooted, application cannot reconnect to that specific database, though it is accessible via network.

Even i tried to restart my application programmatically to re-establish the connection. But, It also fails.

Application just throws

**"Disk or Network error"**

or

**"Unspecified Error"**

or

**"Cannot start your application. The workgroup information file is missing or opened exclusively by another user."**

Anyone?

Comment: Some code may help.  Are you trying to re-open the connection after it comes back online?

Comment: Jet/ACE cannot recover a connection once it's lost. That is, if the remote machine is rebooted, you need to re-initialize your connection from scratch. There is no recovery, ever.

Comment: David's comment was perfect. Jet is horrible with regard to its ability to recover from a failed connection. A loss of a single packet will take down your connection. We recommend to all of our users that they only use a shared database on an actual server (never a user's workstation), and NEVER EVER across a VPN connection.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

Actually, I'm using static object with the following piece of code for each of the databases associated with the application.

```
DbProviderFactory factory;
DbConnection connection;
DbDataAdapter dataAdapter;

void SetConnection(ConnectionStringSettings settings) {
    factory = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(settings.ProviderName);
    if (factory != null) {
        if (connection == null) {
            connection = factory.CreateConnection();
            dataAdapter = factory.CreateDataAdapter();                    
            connection.ConnectionString = settings.ConnectionString;
        }
    }
}

public DataTable GetTable(string statement) {
    DataTable dataTable = null;
    if (connection != null) {
       dataAdapter.SelectCommand = connection.CreateCommand();
       dataAdapter.SelectCommand.CommandText = statement;
       dataTable = new DataTable();
       dataAdapter.Fill(dataTable);
    }
    else
       throw new Exception("Connection object null");

    return dataTable;
}
```

I am setting the connection string and provider name from the app.config.